# mongoose bulk update and code optimization

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need help updating my old records. What I am doing is I'm changing the old records to the new DB structure. In old element.name was a string and now I'm changing it to object. and also I'm removing some unnecessary keys from objects. everything is working fine but I have a large amount of data. I want to update records in an efficient way. any way to update it once or in chunks? Thanks

```
async function convertOldToNew() {
  const progresses = await this.progressModel
    .find({})
    .select({ habitos: 1, answers: 1 });
  progresses.forEach(async (progress) => {
    if (progress.answers) {
      progress.answers.forEach((element) => {
        element.name = { es: element.name };
      });
    }
    if (progress.habitos) {
      if (progress.habitos.residuos && progress.habitos.residuos.length > 0) {
        progress.habitos.residuos = progress.habitos.residuos.map((element) => {
          element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
          delete element['name'];
          delete element['how'];
          delete element['why'];
          return element;
        });
      }
      if (progress.habitos.consumo && progress.habitos.consumo.length > 0) {
        progress.habitos.consumo = progress.habitos.consumo.map((element) => {
          element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
          delete element['name'];
          delete element['how'];
          delete element['why'];
          return element;
        });
      }
      if (
        progress.habitos.transporte &&
        progress.habitos.transporte.length > 0
      ) {
        progress.habitos.transporte = progress.habitos.transporte.map(
          (element) => {
            element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
            delete element['name'];
            delete element['how'];
            delete element['why'];
            return element;
          }
        );
      }
    }
    await progress.save();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic I came up with.

```
     async convertOldToNew() {
    const totalProgress = await this.progressModel
      .find({
        $or: [
          { answers: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
          { 'habitos.consumo': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
          { 'habitos.residuos': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
          { 'habitos.transporte': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
        ],
      })
      .count();
    for (let i = 0; i < totalProgress; i++) {
      let limitCounter = 1000;
      let skipCounter = 0;
      const progresses = await this.progressModel
        .find({
          $or: [
            { answers: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
            { 'habitos.consumo': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
            { 'habitos.residuos': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
            { 'habitos.transporte': { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
          ],
        })
        .select({ habitos: 1, answers: 1 })
        .limit(i == 0 ? limitCounter : limitCounter + 1000)
        .skip(i == 0 ? skipCounter : skipCounter + 1000);
      if (progresses.length > 0) {
        progresses.forEach(async progress => {
          if (progress.answers) {
            progress.answers.forEach(element => {
              element.name = { es: element.name };
            });
          }
          if (progress.habitos) {
            if (progress.habitos.residuos && progress.habitos.residuos.length > 0) {
              progress.habitos.residuos = progress.habitos.residuos.map(element => {
                element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
                delete element['name'];
                delete element['how'];
                delete element['why'];
                return element;
              });
            }
            if (progress.habitos.consumo && progress.habitos.consumo.length > 0) {
              progress.habitos.consumo = progress.habitos.consumo.map(element => {
                element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
                delete element['name'];
                delete element['how'];
                delete element['why'];
                return element;
              });
            }
            if (progress.habitos.transporte && progress.habitos.transporte.length > 0) {
              progress.habitos.transporte = progress.habitos.transporte.map(element => {
                element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
                delete element['name'];
                delete element['how'];
                delete element['why'];
                return element;
              });
            }
          }
          await progress.save();
        });
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```